# Approximation of length of monotone curve

Tags: geometry

Recently, I am interesting about some geometry problem. One of them is:

> Let $f$ is monotone and has continuous derivative on $[a,b]$. Then
>
> $lf\le\Delta f+\Delta h$
>
> where $lf$ denote the length of the curve
>   $f$, $\Delta f=|f(b)-f(a)|$ and $\Delta h=|b-a|$.

An instance of $f$ is shown in the following picture. (The picture is ugly since the x-axis. But I do not know how to scaling it in GeoBebra. Please forgive me.→_→)

[image: A monotone curve]

Indeed, this proposition can be proved easily when we use line integral. Assume $f'\ge0$, then
$$
lf-\Delta f=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'^2}dx-\int_a^bf'dx\le\int_a^b\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}+f'}dx\le\int_a^b1dx=\Delta h
$$
$f'\le0$ is similar to this proof. However, what I want to prove is the validation of the line integral under some conditions. So, in my problem, line integral method is not available. Thus, I am wondering **are there some geometry or topology methods to prove this proposition**? I am not familiar with geometry field, so I do not know are there some existent theorems about it.

My try:

I had read a Loo-keng Hua's book once and I had inspired by the book. Let make some auxiliary lines as is shown in the following picture. As we all know, in triangle, if $\angle A>\angle B$ then $a>b$. So my try is to show that $\overset{\frown}{AD}\le\Delta h$ and $\overset{\frown}{OD}\le\Delta f$. But I can not prove my guess because I can not approx the upper bound of the curve.

[image: Auxiliary lines]

Can you help me to solve this problem or give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pick $n+1$ points on the curve, say $(x_0,f(x_0)), (x_1,f(x_1)), \ldots, (x_n,f(x_n))$ with $x_0=a$ and $x_n=b$. Connect them by line segments. For the line segment from $(x_i,f(x_i))$ to $(x_{i+1},f(x_{i+1}))$, draw a right triangle and observe that by the triangle inequality, the length of the line segment is not more than $|x_{i+1}-x_i| + |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|$. The absolute values go away becuase $f$ is monotonic, and the sum over all $n$ line segments telescopes to $(b-a)+(f(b)-f(a))$.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for your answer. In fact, what I want to prove is that the sum of line segments converges to the length of curve when $f\in C^1$. So it seems the answer use the conclusion that what I want to prove.

Comment: Isn't that the [*definition* of the length of the curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Definition)?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that is right. But this definition is mathematical. I want to prove the proposition is right for the 'real length'. That is, 'stretch' the curve to a line and measure of it. Actually, I want to prove the definition will converges to the 'real length'.